# Get all business recommended fields in subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, subgrid, webresource

How do I check if a particular field or column of a subgrid is business recommend or not? I want to do this using a web resource. Also due to some requirements, I will have to use the execution context of the form where the subgrid is present and not of the subgrid itself.

Comment: Its not clear - what are you trying to do after finding the subgrid record mandatory fields?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little tricky because at the time that the form loads, the subgrid does not have data. So you have to use the Form's `load` event to attach a `load` event to the subgrid.

This is described in this [MS Docs Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/events/subgrid-onload). You can do this like

```
function attachGridEvent(executionContext)
{
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  var gridContext = formContext.getControl("gridCategories");

  // We have the grid, now add a "load" event handler
  gridContext.addOnLoad(MyGridLoadedEvent);
}
```

Now you've got a 'load' event for your grid so you can iterate through its rows and examine its data

***I haven't been able to get this to work for subgrids that don't contain data***

I get the first `row` in the sub grid. Once I have that we can loop through each of the row's `attributes`. Each attribute has the following methods:

> **getName**   Returns the logical name of the attribute of a selected grid
>   row.
>
> **getRequiredLevel**  Returns a string value indicating whether a
>   value for the attribute is required or recommended.
>
> **setRequiredLevel**  Sets whether data is required or recommended for the
>   attribute of a selected grid row before the record can be saved.
>
> **getValue**  Retrieves the data value for an attribute.
>
> **setValue**  Sets the
>   data value for an attribute.

[MS Docs Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/grids/gridattribute)

I'm using some modern browser features (`map`, `=>`) but this code should work for you

```
function MyGridLoadedEvent(evt)
{
  var gridContext = evt.getEventSource();
  var rows = gridContext.getGrid().getRows();

  if (rows.getLength() > 0)
  {
    let rowAttributes = rows.getByIndex(0).getAttribute();
    let mappedResults = rowAttributes.map(x => x.getName() + " : " + x.getRequiredLevel());

    alert(mappedResults);
  }
}
```